# How to download a file through an SSH server?

Tags: ssh, wget

I have a server in USA (Linux box B), and my home PC (Linux box A),
and I need download a file from website C,

The issue is, it is very slow to download a file direct from A,
so I need download the file when I log in B, and `sftp` get the file from A.

Is there any way that I can download file and use B as proxy directly through only one line command?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

(Strange situation, doesn't something like the [triangle inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_inequality) hold for internet routing?)

Anyway, try the following, on **A**, `ssh` into **B** with a `-D` argument,

```
ssh -D 1080 address-of-B
```

which acts as a SOCKS5 proxy on `127.0.0.1:1080`, which can be used by anything supporting SOCKS5 proxied connections.  [Apparently, `wget` can do this](https://superuser.com/a/262972/102592), by using the environment variable

```
export SOCKS_SERVER=127.0.0.1:1080
wget http://server-C/whatever
```

Note that sometimes `curl` is more handy (i.e. I'm not sure if `wget` can do hostname lookups via SOCKS5; but this is not one of your concerns I suppose); also Firefox is able to work completely through such a SOCKS5 proxy.

**Edit** I've just now noticed that you're looking for a **one-line** solution.  Well, how about

```
ssh address-of-B 'wget -O - http://server-C/whatever' >> whatever
```

i.e. redirection the `wget`-fetched output to `stdout`, and redirecting the local output (from `ssh` running `wget` remotely) to a file.

This seems to work, the `wget` output is just a little confusing ("*saved to -*"), you can get rid of it by adding `-q` to the `wget` call.

Comment: Apparently the `SOCKS_SERVER` environment variable has no effect on Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: According to [this other answer](https://superuser.com/a/262972/10758), `wget` has no support for `SOCKS_SERVER` variable. That answer suggests using `curl --socks5-hostname` or `curl --socks5`.

Comment: @kasperd, so, is it just ubuntu where it doesn't work, or is the variable not related to wget at all?  it appears that the variable might be for `socksify` instead.

Comment: @cnst I have seen no evidence that any version of wget has socks support. `socksify` is not a setting, it is a separate program.

Comment: so, basically, if you want `SOCKS_SERVER` to have any effect on `wget`, then you have to install http://ports.su/security/dante, and then run `socksify wget` instead of just `wget`

Answer (score 3):

Another approach could be that you normally log in into `B`, where you start a `screen` session. There you do the `wget` of your files - all into one directory.

And there the program can happily run; you just detach from screen, but let it run in the background.

If the downloads are finished (maybe even earlier), you can fech the data from `B` to `A` using `rsync` (my preference).

Answer (score 2):

Inspired by [another answer to another question](https://superuser.com/a/504119), I suggest using [proxychains-ng](https://github.com/rofl0r/proxychains-ng) (which is the newer version of [proxychains](http://proxychains.sourceforge.net/)).

1. Download, compile, and optionally install [proxychains-ng](https://github.com/rofl0r/proxychains-ng).
2. Create a `proxychains.conf` file in the current directory, or at `~/.proxychains/proxychains.conf`, or at `/etc/proxychains.conf`.

   - Alternatively, create one file anywhere else, or with another name, and specify if through `-f` command-line argument, or through `PROXYCHAINS_CONF_FILE` environment variable.
   - There is a [sample config file](https://github.com/rofl0r/proxychains-ng/blob/master/src/proxychains.conf) available. The most relevant options are at the very end.
3. In your `proxychains.conf` file, add:

   ```
   [ProxyList]
   socks5 127.0.0.1 1234
   ```
4. Run `ssh -D 1234 your_host_b`. This will make ssh listen on port 1234 on localhost, and use your remote host as a SOCKS proxy.

   - Alternatively, run `ssh -ND 1234 your_host_b` instead. `-N` will prevent ssh from running any command on the remote server (i.e. it won't open a shell).
5. Run: `proxychains4 yourcommandhere yourparametershere`. See some examples:

   - `proxychains4 wget -O - http://ifconfig.co/`
   - `proxychains4 -q links http://ifconfig.co/`

Answer (score 2):

## Option 0:

In order to use [`wget`](http://ports.su/net/wget) with a SOCKS5 proxy from [`ssh`](http://mdoc.su/o/ssh), you have to install the [`security/dante`](http://ports.su/security/dante) package in order to use the `SOCKS_SERVER` option with the `socksify` utility.

```
sudo pkg_add dante
```

Subsequently, you open an SSH connection in the background:

```
ssh -N -C -D1080 user@hostB &
```

And use wget through a SOCKS5 proxy through socksify:

```
env SOCKS_SERVER=127.0.0.1:1080 socksify wget http://website-C
```

---

## Option 1:

Just pipe the file to `stdout` on the server, and read it from `stdin` on your workstation.

```
ssh -C user@hostB "wget -O- http://website-C" >> file-from-website-C
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do a ssh tunnel from box A to box B and add to the routing table in box A, that website C is reachable via tunnel to box B. You have to allow packet forwarding on the box B.

[Here](http://bodhizazen.net/Tutorials/VPN-Over-SSH) you can see a very good step-by-step tutorial...

Answer (score 1):

You would need to create a tunnel on machine B tha would redirect the call to website C. But I'm puzzled as why this would be faster, unless your ISP as some restrictions.

I don't know a oneliner, but this isn't much more complicated.

On machine A, you do (I took 11111 randomly, you can take whatever you want as long as it is > 1024, or you would need to be root)

```
ssh -f -C -N -L 11111:C:80 username@B
```

The username on B is the one you use to connect to B. This should create a tunnel on port 11111 on machine B that redirect to port 80 (web site in HTTP use 443 for HTTPS) on machine C (I hope I did not mess the order ;) )

Then you can download the file directly from machine A via machine B. I'm assuming the file is at `http://C/path/to/file` so you would then use:

```
wget http://B:11111/path/to/file
```

Comment: Wouldn't this work only if the file is accessible without HTTP 1.1 name-based virtual hosting? Since the GET request issued by wget would state the hostname as B, not C.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling I don't have enough knowledge to answer you.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this via port forwarding (ssh tunneling).  Here's a resource:
http://www.jfranken.de/homepages/johannes/vortraege/ssh2_inhalt.en.html#ToC9

Essentially, you should set up port forwarding on B.  When A issues wget to B, B will forward the packets to C and send the results back to A.