# Tunnel HTTP traffic using another machine via SSH

Tags: ssh, proxy, port-forwarding, socks

I have this situation:

server 1: public ip  x.x.x.x
          private ip 192.168.0.1

server 2: private ip 192.168.0.10

The server 1 can reach the internet with both interfaces:

```
ping -i x.x.x.x www.google.com
www.google.com is alive

ping -i 192.168.0.1 www.google.com
www.google.com is alive
```

The server 2 can reach only the server 1 via ssh. I need to update some packages and install some new ones on this server (all shell commands). I tried already using:

```
ssh -D 9001 root@server1
```

and exporting http_proxy/ftp_proxy with localhost:9001 on server 2, but it seems to not work. How can I use the public connection of server 1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `-D` option enables a SOCKS4/5 server. It is not identical to an normal HTTP/FTP-proxy and need therefore to be interfaced differently. A lot of browser support SOCKS proxies, but usually not via a http_proxy/ftp_proxy environment variable.

You can wrap programs, which do not support SOCKS directly, with [tsocks](http://tsocks.sourceforge.net/index.php).

See also https://superuser.com/questions/262956/how-to-invoke-a-command-using-specific-proxy-server and [How to download a file through an SSH server?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/38755/how-to-download-a-file-through-an-ssh-server)